# Old Objective c code assign __weak

Tags: objective-c

In the old code of objective c

there are some .h file that have @property declare as follow:

> @property (nonatomic, assign) __weak XXXObject *state

Since in later iOS version, this code is no longer valid and in XCode 8.3.3,

following exception thrown and the program can't build:

> Unsafe_unretained property 'state' may not also be declared __weak

May i ask what is the behavior of the old code for declaring both assign and __Weak, and in order to solve the exception thrown, what's the best way to change the declaration of the property?

Comment: You’d generally just do `@property (nonatomic, weak) XXXObject *state`. The only difference is that once there are no more strong references, it will automatically set it to `nil` rather than potentially leaving you w dangling pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's means the original code `@property (nonatomic, assign) __weak` have both strong and weak reference??

Comment: No, `assign` is not a strong reference. But it says "don't establish strong reference nor set it to `nil` when the object is deallocated". And that conflicts with `weak`, which _will_ `nil` the pointer when the object is deallocated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, and one more question, will it have any difference if i change the code to `@property (nonatomic /* , assign */) __weak` compare to the code you mentioned `@property (nonatomic, weak)` ?

Comment: I have no idea because that's not how you declare weak properties. The correct syntax is `@property (nonatomic, weak) XXXObject *state;` (though, obviously the choice of `atomic` vs `nonatomic` depends upon your needs, but we generally use `nonatomic`). I'm not sure why you'd contemplate doing it any other way.